# How to Handle File Existence Check in `configure.ac` When Cross Compiling on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, autotools, autoconf, m4, autoreconf

I am working on [a project](https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica) that requires conditional compilation based on the presence of certain files, specifically for integrating IPOPT (an optimization library). My development environment is Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), and I face cross-compilation challenges.

In my `configure.ac`, I have a custom macro `IPOPT_ARG_CHECK` that checks for the existence of `IpStdCInterface.h` as part of determining whether to compile with IPOPT support. Here's the relevant part of the macro:

```
AC_DEFUN([IPOPT_ARG_CHECK],
[
    ...
    AC_ARG_WITH([$1],
       [AS_HELP_STRING([--$2],
         [IPOPT installation directory @<:@default=check@:>@])],
       [$1=$withval],
       [$3=no])

    AS_IF([test "x$$3" = xno],
          [...],
          [AC_CHECK_FILE($$1/include/$coin/IpStdCInterface.h,
                         [],
                         [AC_MSG_FAILURE([--$2 option was specified but does not seem to point at a valid IPOPT installation])])])

    AM_CONDITIONAL([$8],[test "x$$3" != xno])
    ...
])
```

However, I get a warning when I run `autoreconf`:

> configure.ac:242: warning: cannot check for file existence when cross compiling

I'm looking for guidance on the canonical way to perform this check in a cross-compilation-friendly manner.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that `AC_CHECK_FILE` is not recommended for cross-compilation scenarios. Based on suggestions ([here](https://forums.packetizer.com/viewtopic.php?t=189) and [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-arm-kernel/patch/20161215122718.21422-2-andre.przywara@arm.com/)), I replaced it with a simple `test -f` check:

```
AS_IF([test -f "$$1/include/$coin/IpStdCInterface.h"],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT([found])],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])
       AC_MSG_ERROR([--$2 option was specified but does not seem to point at a valid IPOPT installation])])
```

And that resolved the issue.

However, I believe the canonical way to perform this check in a cross-compilation-friendly manner is to rewrite the `IPOPT_ARG_CHECK` function using the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro from the pkg-config system. It seems to be a more robust and common approach to handling dependencies in `configure.ac`, especially for cross-compilation scenarios. This macro checks for the existence of a package and its version and sets up `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` variables accordingly, which can then be used in the Makefiles.

**P.S.** I had already mentioned this method in the question as a failed attempt, but then later, I realized that I had a syntax error, and by fixing that, this worked. I also wrote about this solution [here](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn/issues/446#issuecomment-2003999395).

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a project that requires conditional compilation based on the presence of certain files, specifically for integrating IPOPT (an optimization library). [...] I face cross-compilation challenges.

In this particular case, that's because you have framed the problem in an unhelpful way.  You don't just want to generically check for a file.  Rather, you want to check whether a working (for your purposes) IPOPT library has been configured.  You should do that via `AC_CHECK_HEADER`, `AC_CHECK_LIB`, *etc*, not via `AC_CHECK_FILE`.

If you're already performing such checks then your `AC_CHECK_FILE` is unneeded.  If you're not performing them, then you probably should be.  Especially for good cross-compilation support, as these will verify that the configured library is compatible with your cross toolchain.

`AC_CHECK_FILE` is almost never the right tool for the job.  Any job.

Comment: can I just replace the whole thing with `AC_CHECK_HEADER([IpStdCInterface.h])`? Could you be kind to elaborate?

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani, the code presented in the question is too abbreviated and out of context for me to recommend a direct replacement, whether for the whole thing or for any particular part of it.  My impression is that you are making things too complicated.  I would just (1) define the `--with` argument, and accept and store the resulting value, and (2) perform conventional tests for the headers and libraries you need.  If you are trying to decide whether to use ipopt at all, then base that on whether the `--with` argument is provided, not on whether the check for it passes.